# SSRS Font weight between 2005 and 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an RDL which was in 2005 report server.

By using an updated IDE, it converts the 2005 RDL to 2008 RDL.

There is an issue about font weight. In 2005, font weight can be specified as an integer.

```
<FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
```

And IDE converts it to

```
<FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
```

As font weight cannot be an integer in 2008 version.

However font weight [Bold] is not as thick as [700], in this 2005 report, these two value are applied.

Is there any way to implement the 700 properly in the 2008 RDL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Bold` should match a font weight of 700, but if you need to make it darker try `ExtraBold` (weight 800) or `Heavy` (weight 900).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240142(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: it looks like i didn't see different among Bold, ExtraBold or Heavy, i rendered it directly from visual studio with report service installed